# Select pandas column for each row by index list

Tags: python, pandas

In the following code, how can I select data2's element each row that is given by the list of column index, `data.idxmax(axis=1)`?

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [4,3], [5,6]])
data2 = pd.DataFrame([[10,20], [30,40], [50,60]])
data1.idxmax(axis=1)
```

The result should be pd.Series or pd.DataFrame of `[20,30,60]`.

Comment: `data1.idxmax(axis=1)` gave you a list of numeric column-indices. How do you ever index into a df using a list of numeric column-indices? What's the function, according to the pandas documentation? Post us what you've tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) function:

```
i = data1.idxmax(axis=1)
data2.lookup(i.index, i.values)
```

This will give you an array with the values. To get the result as a `Series`, simply create it:

```
pd.Series(data2.lookup(i.index, i.values))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `max` with `axis = 1` and `eq` with `axis = 0`

```
data2[data1.eq(data1.max(1),0)].stack()
Out[193]: 
0  1    20.0
1  0    30.0
2  1    60.0
dtype: float64
```